# Power BI - Summarize table by 2 different date column

Tags: powerbi, dax, summarize

I have a table with information about our projects. I want to create a graphic showing number of projects started and finished each month. The original table looks like this:

| Project ID | Start Date | Finish Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/10/2021 | 08/19/2021 |
| 2 | 02/15/2021 | 06/22/2021 |
| 3 | 05/08/2021 | 08/12/2021 |
| 4 | 06/25/2021 | 08/16/2021 |
| 5 | 06/29/2021 | 11/30/2021 |
| 6 | 08/12/2021 | 12/05/2021 |

The result table should look like this:

| Month | Started | Finished |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 05/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 06/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 08/2021 | 1 | 3 |
| 11/2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 12/2021 | 0 | 1 |

I've tried to use SUMMARIZE, but I haven't found a way to "group" 2 different dates in only 1 column.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a Calendar Table.

## Calendar Table

```
Calendar =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR ( MIN ( 'Table'[Start Date] ), MAX ( 'Table'[Finish Date] ) ),
    "Month Year", FORMAT ( [Date], "mm/yyyy" )
)
```

From there, you can create your DAX calculations

### Started

```
Started =
VAR _SelectedMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Month Year] )
VAR _FilterCalendar =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( 'Calendar', [Month Year] = _SelectedMonth ),
        "@Date", [Date]
    )
VAR _Result =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Start Date] IN _FilterCalendar )
RETURN
    _Result
```

### Finished

```
Finished =
VAR _SelectedMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Month Year] )
VAR _FilterCalendar =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( 'Calendar', [Month Year] = _SelectedMonth ),
        "@Date", [Date]
    )
VAR _Result =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Finish Date] IN _FilterCalendar )
RETURN
    _Result
```

## Output

[image]